# Visual Studio c++ include string maximum length

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

I've been trying to compile Qt on Windows and I've run into an interesting problem with #includes failing with the error that the file being included does not exist ("No such file or directory").  However the file does exist.  The files doing the including are auto-generated "moc" files (made by Qt) that have an include like the following:

`#include "../../../../../../../../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2/examples/tools/plugandpaintplugins/extrafilters/extrafiltersplugin.h"`

The string in that include is 127 characters long.  There are many "moc" files produced and compiled in the build, but only ones with very long lengths like this (127+ characters) fail.

The files in question happen to be sitting on a UNIX system, shared via Samba to Windows.  I was able to work around the issue by creating a symlink and replacing "qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2" with "qt-4.8.2" in the affected files.  The resulting include:

`#include "../../../../../../../../qt-4.8.2/examples/tools/plugandpaintplugins/extrafilters/extrafiltersplugin.h"`

is only 102 characters long and works just fine.

I've searched around and could not find any reference to this.  Nor could I replicate the problem outside this Qt build (just making arbitrarily long file names and trying to include them).  So it's possible that somehow the `nmake` makefiles that Qt creates are doing something when they run `cl` that causes it to reject long includes in some way.

Does anyone have any additional information on this?

Comment: what is the length of the absolute path in both cases? i.e. when resolving the various ../../. There is a maximum path limit of 256 characters on most old windows systems.

Comment: The full path for this example is 132 and 106 characters, respectively.  But the OS has no trouble opening the file (i.e., in Notepad or the cmd shell).

btw, I forgot to mention I'm using MSVS 2008.

Comment: I did use a Samba mount when I failed to replicate the problem.  Based on some other comments I found online I thought it might be the directory length not the file length, so I made some really long fake directories, but still no problem.  But then I tried putting the source file IN the long directory and including ../../really-long-dir/7890123...890/a.h and I got the error.  That happens up to about 131 characters.  But I can have longer total path lengths with fewer ".." in the path.  Very weird.  I wonder if this is a bug in the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is used to find the included file, I tend to believe that it is connected to the OS' file path restrictions.

Maybe the implementation of the preprocessor somehow restricts it too, but that would be specific for each and every compiler.

Answer (score 0):

At one of my working places in the past, we had another similar problem. The project was very large and had so much files that the compiler command that Visual Studio generates when building the project was so long that it exceeded some limit and compilation failed. This, however, was happening on Visual Studio 2008, I do not know about newer ones.

I know it is unrelated but this is just additional information. It may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a limitation set by the .NET framework but haven't found the exact line on this yet.

Here are some interesting links on this: on [social msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/vssetup/thread/4007ecaf-7c44-4ceb-be46-a9a2c8b351b5) and [blog msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/mohamedg/archive/2007/12/14/file-system-limits.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same issue when building projects using GCC on windows.
The issue seems to relate to the way in which the Path is assembled,

`../../../../../../../../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2/examples/tools/plugandpaintplugins/extrafilters/extrafiltersplugin.h`

becomes

`c:/some/working/structure/that_is/at_least/as_deep/as_the_up/levels/are/../../../../../../../../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2/examples/tools/plugandpaintplugins/extrafilters/extrafiltersplugin.h`

(example may not be to scale, I didn't count characters...)
At this point the path-handling breaks down due to being too long. In our case, forcing the compiler to use a contracted version,

`c:/some/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2/examples/tools/plugandpaintplugins/extrafilters/extrafiltersplugin.h`

would make the problem go away.
MSDN does contain some hints of the problem at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) 
Note that the alternative,longer supporting, path format, \?\, does not seem to support relative paths.

**Quick Fix**: Don't use relative paths of such depth.

Answer (score 0):

You should just add the path you are reffering to to compiler options, rather than use something THAT horrible.

Comment: Both the makefile and the includes in question are autogenerated by the Qt build system.  I have limited control over them.  Fortunately, this is a one time build, not something I do every day.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the 'project' tab and unchecking 'Shadow build' solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

i came across exactly same issue recently, when building qt on windows using msys & mingw. Build system was unable to find header file included via following relative path:

> "../../../../../../../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.0.1/qtbase/src/platformsupport/fontdatabases/basic/qbasicfontdatabase_p.h"

But file was present and the path was correct as well.

I created a similar file structure outside of qt source tree and was able to reproduce the issue using g++ from command line.

I tinkered a bit, by reducing number of filename characters one at a time. Five characters down and the errors vanished. g++ suddenly found the file.

It worked when **total characters in include statement** were equal to **120**.
This is just a quantitative figure to give a rough idea what might be the limit under the hood. It might be different for different versions of compiler. I don't think OS has any part in determining it. This bottleneck seems more due to pre-processor.